# Nano issue with Solarized Theme Terminal Mac OS X

Tags: terminal, nano

When opening up nano when using the solarized terminal theme the screen refresh doesn't seem to work. It also sometimes starts the first character of a line on the end of the previous line. Which always happens on the first line of the file. I have tested this and know its the solarized theme as I have changed themes and it doesn't happen on that theme.

Also when opening a file with lots of lines when I scroll down it sometimes doesn't refresh the page as blank so when it redraws the next page it shows the info from that page instead of some from the previous.

I am also using zsh.
If you need any other info please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just come across the same problem.  I resolved it by going to the *Advanced* tab and changing *Declare terminal as* from `ansi` to `xterm-256color`.